# Signing out of AWS Cognito user Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc, amazon-cognito

I've build a basic .Net Core web application using AWS cognito for user authentication.  I've been following this example... https://www.developerhandbook.com/aws/how-to-use-aws-cognito-with-net-core/

But I'm unsure how to construct a proper sign out process.  I've tried calling the logout endpoint as documented here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/logout-endpoint.html.

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var region = "eu-west-2";
            var protocol = "https://";
            var userPoolDomain = $"my-domain.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com";
            var clientId = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
            var appUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://localhost:44374/signin-oidc");
            var scope = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:Scope"]; 
            var url = $"{protocol}{userPoolDomain}/logout?client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={appUrl}&response_type=code&state=STATE&scope={scope}";
            await client.GetAsync(url);
        };
        return View();
    }
```

The Get request returns a 200 response, but when I navigate to another page requiring authentication it does not redirect to the Cognito signup UI page.

I've also tried...

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> LogOut()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return View();
    }
```

But that was similarly unsuccessful. I'm assume that I'm probably barking up the wrong tree, but haven't had much success searching for a solution & I'm not sure what else to try?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working in the end...

```
    public void LogOutUser()
    {
        DeleteCookies();
        HitCognitoEndPoint();
    }

    public IActionResult LogOut()
    {
        return View();
    }

    private void HitCognitoEndPoint()
    {
        var region = "eu-west-2";
        var protocol = "https://";
        var userPoolDomain = $"e-q-s-helloworld.auth.{region}.amazoncognito.com";
        var clientId = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:ClientId"];
        var appUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("https://localhost:44374/Home/Logout");
        var scope = Configuration["Authentication:Cognito:Scope"]; // "openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin";
        //var url = $"{protocol}{userPoolDomain}/logout?client_id={clientId}&redirect_uri={appUrl}&response_type=code&state=STATE&scope={scope}";
        var url = $"{protocol}{userPoolDomain}/logout?client_id={clientId}&logout_uri={appUrl}";
        Response.Redirect(url);
    }

    private void DeleteCookies()
    {
        foreach (var cookie in Request.Cookies.Keys)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie);
        }
    }
```